# Maple polynomial equation solver not identifying solutions

Tags: solver, maple

I have a polynomial in four variables and would like to use Maple to find all the solutions to F = n for particular values of n over the integers (so I am using isolve). F (below) is defined with a factor of 1/2 but it turns out to always be an integer, assuming the inputs are all integers.

In line 1 I define F. In line 2 I check that F=5 has an integer solution. In line 3 Maple says that there are no solutions to F=5. Here is the code I gave it:

```
F := 1/2*((e + h + f + i)*(e + h + f + i - 1) + (-1 - e - f)*(-2 - e - f) + (-h - i)*(-h - i - 1) + (-1 - e - h)*(-2 - e - h) + e*(e - 1) + h*(h - 1) + (-1 - f - i)*(-2 - f - i) + f*(f - 1) + i*(i - 1)):

F(-1, 0, 1, 0);
                               5

isolve(F(e, h, f, i) = 5);
```

Maple doesn't return anything for the last line. Is this just a case of something that it cannot handle? I asked a friend to try this in a different language, and they were able to get Mathematica to find all solutions for various n values with no problem, though I didn't check what exactly they did.